# Nesper - LoaderExceptions

Tags: c#, devexpress, nesper

I am building a Nesper application and after deployment it throws this error:

```
System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes()
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
   at com.espertech.esper.script.ScriptingServiceImpl.DiscoverEngines(Assembly assembly, Predicate`1 isEngine)
   at com.espertech.esper.script.ScriptingServiceImpl.DiscoverEngines(Predicate`1 isEngine)
   at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPServicesContextFactoryDefault.CreateServicesContext(EPServiceProvider epServiceProvider, ConfigurationInformation configSnapshot)
   at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPServiceProviderImpl.DoInitialize(Nullable`1 startTime)
   at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPServiceProviderImpl..ctor(Configuration configuration, String engineURI, IDictionary`2 runtimes)
   at com.espertech.esper.client.EPServiceProviderManager.GetProvider(String providerURI, Configuration configuration)
```

Answer (score 0):

After I printed the LoaderExceptions, it shows that these two libraries are missing:

1. DevExpress.Printing.v13.2.Core
2. DevExpress.Sparkline.v13.2.Core